# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react js to create a staycation website, when I want to display the `InputNumber` and `InputDate` components I experience an error like the title above, in the `componentDidUpdate` section, I have tried tweaking the code but it hasn't worked, but when I omit the `componentDidUpdate` part, the `inputdate` and `inputnumber` components run

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import propTypes from "prop-types";

import Button from "elements/Button";
import { InputNumber, InputDate } from "elements/Form";

export default class BookingForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {`enter code here`
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        duration: 1,
        date: {
          startDate: new Date(),
          endDate: new Date(),
          key: "selection",
        },
      },
    };
  }

  updateData = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      },
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (prevState.data.date !== data.date) {
      const startDate = new Date(data.date.startDate);
      const endDate = new Date(data.date.endDate);
      const countDuration = new Date(endDate - startDate).getDate();
      this.setState({
        data: {
          ...this.state.data,
          duration: countDuration,
        },
      });
    }
    if (prevState.data.duration !== data.duration) {
      const starDate = new Date(data.date.startDate);
      const endDate = new Date(
        starDate.setDate(starDate.getDate() + +data.duration - 1)
      );
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        data: {
          ...this.state.data,
          date: {
            ...this.state.data.date,
            endDate: endDate,
          },
        },
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { itemDetails, startBooking } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="card bordered" style={{ padding: "60px 80px" }}>
        <h4 className="mb-3">Start Booking</h4>
        <h5 className="h2 text-teal mb-4">
          ${itemDetails.price}{" "}
          <span className="text-gray-500 font-weight-light">
            per {itemDetails.unit}
          </span>
        </h5>

        <label htmlFor="duration">How long you will stay?</label>
        <InputNumber
          max={30}
          suffix={" night"}
          isSuffixPlural
          onChange={this.updateData}
          name="duration"
          value={data.duration}
        />

        <label htmlFor="date">Pick a date</label>
        <InputDate onChange={this.updateData} name="date" value={data.date} />
        <h6
          className="text-gray-500 font-weight-light"
          style={{ marginBottom: 40 }}
        >
          You will pay{" "}
          <span className="text-gray-900">
            ${itemDetails.price * data.duration} USD
          </span>{" "}
          <span className="text-gray-900">
            {data.duration} {itemDetails.unit}
          </span>
        </h6>

        <Button
          className="btn"
          hasShadow
          isPrimary
          isBlock
          onClik={startBooking}
        >
          Continue to Book
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BookingForm.propTypes = {
  itemDetails: propTypes.object,
  startBooking: propTypes.func,
};
```

Comment: Isn't `prevState.data.date !== data.date` and setState together will loop infinitely. I think you should check condition in `shouldComponentUpdate` hook?

Comment: When `state.data.date` changes you update `state.data.duration`, and when `state.data.duration` updates you update `state.data.date`... this creates an update cycle. Based on your input name for the date it's a little unclear what you want the input to update. Is it the start date, or is it the end date? What does that input return for the handler to update in state besides a `date` name/property?